# Serving image overlays with react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to display an 'animated' overlay using multiple images on a map using react-native-maps. Currently I am storing the image id I need in state, and using that to determine the path of my remote image in the overlay component like so:

```js
<Overlay
   image={{ uri: `my-backend/public/${id-from-state}.png` }}
/>
```

This works but when I'm cycling through all the images by updating the image id I ofcourse encounter performance issues since every time the images are being fetched again. I'm guessing there is also no caching going on behind the scenes in react-native-maps so even when I'm requesting the same image, it's fetched again, flooding my backend unnecessarily.

I was thinking of a few solutions, in the hope someone here could help me out properly serving these images.

---

**1. Serving images via cdn**

This could speed up delivery of the images, but still doesn't solve the issue of caching the images on the client. This would only remove some heat from my backend. Okay solution, but doesn't seem like the right thing.

**2. Downloading images / using base64**

Serving the images locally from the client, could be as base64. This way I only need to request the images once and they can be loaded the same way but now from local cache. I think this is the *easiest* solution for my use case.

**3. Rendering the overlay via a custom tile server**

This requires a lot of setting up and is probably a bit overkill for my use case, but would probably be the best performance wise.

**4. Not using react-native-maps?**

I'm currently unaware of another solution that works with react-native, if there are any, please let me know!